# Angular7 Blank page appears whenever route path and component declaration occurs in the app-routes.module.ts

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am setting up a new angular application and whenever I specify my routes in the app-routing.module.ts file the page renders blank.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent},
];
```

However if I comment it out it renders properly.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // {path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  // {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent},
];
```

My **app-routing.moduel.ts** File

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const appRouteComponents = [
  LoginComponent,
  DashboardComponent,
  UserProfileComponent,
  RegisterComponent
];
```

I already imported appRouteComponents in the app.module.ts file

This is **app.module.ts** file

```
import { MaterialDesignModule } from './material';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule, appRouteComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    appRouteComponents,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialDesignModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing **/** in routes as below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];
```